# Resize Form from the Drawn Shape of Panel - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, resize, draw, shapes

I'm trying to make a form resizable based on dragging a custom shape drawn at the corner of the panel. I have a code which works fantastic if it's drawn in the main form, but if I'm trying to draw it at the corner of a panel it doesn't work, I cannot resize the form. The code is optimized to be drawn in the form, could someone help me and update it to work in a panel too?

```
    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
    MyBase.WndProc(m)
    If m.Msg = &H84 Then
        Dim pos = Me.PointToClient(New System.Drawing.Point(m.LParam.ToInt32() And &HFFFF, m.LParam.ToInt32() >> 16))
        If pos.X >= Me.Width - grab AndAlso pos.Y >= Me.Height - grab Then
            m.Result = New IntPtr(17)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
Private Const grab As Integer = 14

Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(e As PaintEventArgs)
    MyBase.OnPaint(e)
    Dim rc = New System.Drawing.Rectangle(Me.Width - grab, Me.Height - grab, grab, grab)
    ControlPaint.DrawSizeGrip(e.Graphics, System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(250, 250, 250), rc)
End Sub
```

It looks like this:

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKhxm.png)

Comment: Google "attribution required".  Tends to be a good way to get the author of this code to help you.

Comment: I got the code from a user of Hackforums.net, I don't really know who the author is. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem by building my own custom control using GDI to paint the shape as standalone control, instead of painting it to an already built control, such panel.